# calling javascript function to print form from code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to call a function javascript function to print the form from code behind on print button click.I m first hiding one column of my gridview on form an then i want to print it.

```
protected void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in grdTransaction.Rows)
    {

        if (UType == "A")
        {
            grdTransaction.Columns[7].Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            grdTransaction.Columns[3].ItemStyle.Width = 100;
            grdTransaction.Columns[5].Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I already used

```
1) ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "Script", 
  "<script type='text/javascript'>clicked('printablediv');</script>", true);

2) ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "Script",
   "clicked('printablediv');", true);

3) btnPrint.Attributea.Add("onclick","clicked('printablediv');");

4) btnPrint.Attributea.Add("onclick","return clicked('printablediv');");
```

All the above options did not work, but on **OnClientClick** event it works..Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the example on msdn [see](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef.aspx) then you'll notice that you have to include a whole script block including  tags.

Furthermore, the OnClientClick event does sound like the right event. So if that works what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**In the first two options :**

that you tried you're simply trying to call a javascript method named `clicked(args)`, so you are not actually binding it to any button click. And you don't have to wrap your script in `<script>` tag when you pass the last argument as `true`. It should work as soon as the page loads.

**now for the last two options of yours:**

see what happens is, when you click on the button, it does postback, therefore you don't see the effect of your javaSript code, because entire page is reloaded. you need to prevent the PostBack.

try this:

```
btnPrint.Attributes.Add("onclick","clicked('printablediv'); return false");
```

make sure, you `return false;` from your clicked method.

also, do take care of semicolon i.e. `;`, when you do control.Attributes.Add, it already appeneds a semicolon; you don't do it your self